# DateTimePicker: disable time zone conversion

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI DateTimePicker and i faced with binding issue. I am getting data from json then i creating new js date based on the json value and bind it. Actual result is that the date is converted to local timezone. Can i disable conversion to local timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTimePicker does not perform any conversion.
I expect that your date does not have time zone specificator and when you creating new js date  this value considered as UTC and converted to local. To solve this problem you can simply bind date from json without creating new js date.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this to add a useUtc option to your code that will always return the date in Utc:

```
kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.valueOld = kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.value;
kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.value = function (e) {
    var val = this._value;
    if (val != null && this.options != null && this.options.useUtc) {
        this._value = new Date(Date.UTC(val.getFullYear(), val.getMonth(), val.getDate()));
    }
    return this.valueOld(e);
}

kendo.ui.DateTimePicker.prototype.valueOld = kendo.ui.DateTimePicker.prototype.value;
kendo.ui.DateTimePicker.prototype.value = function (e) {
    var val = this._value;
    if (val != null && this.options != null && this.options.useUtc) {
        this._value = new Date(Date.UTC(val.getFullYear(), val.getMonth(), val.getDate(), val.getHours(), val.getMinutes(), val.getSeconds(), val.getMilliseconds()));
        }
    return this.valueOld(e);
}
```

Comment: @Victor Thanks!  Glad it was helpful!  Hopefully, it still works with all the version changes that were done.